# Show addition and scalar scalar multiplication of a normed vector space is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I am trying to work out this exercise from Folland chapter 5:

> 1. If $X$ is a normed vector space over $K(=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C})$, then addition and scalar multiplication are continuous from $X \times X$ and $K \times X$ to $X$. Moreover, the norm is continuous from $x$ to $[0, \infty)$; in fact, $|\|x\|-\|y\|| \leq\|x-y\|$.

The product norm is defined to be $\|(x,y)\|=\max(\|x\|,\|y\|)$ (though any equivalent product norm may be uesd such as $\|(x,y)\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$), and the following theorem may be used

> **5.2 Proposition.** If $X$ and $y$ are normed vector spaces and $T: X \rightarrow Y$ is a linear map, the following are equivalent:
>
> a.) $T$ is continuous.
>
> b.) $T$ is continuous at $0$ .
>
> c.) $T$ is bounded.

I am wondering if the bounds I have created are correct.

Let $\varphi_1(x,y)=x+y$ Then $$\|\varphi_1(x,y)\|_X=\|x+y\|_X\leq \|x\|_X+\|y\|_X\leq 2 \max{(\|x\|_X,\|y\|_X)}=2\|(x,y)\|_{X\times X}$$

So this linear operator is bounded and hence is continuous.

For scalar multiplication,

Let $\varphi_2(c,x)=c*x$ Fix $\epsilon >0$. Choose $\|(c,x)\|_{K\times X}\leq \sqrt{\epsilon}.$Then $$\|\varphi_2(c,x)\|_X=\|c*x\|_X\leq |c|\|x\|_X \leq \max{(|c|,\|x\|_X)}^2 < \epsilon$$

So $\varphi_2$ is continuous at $0$ and hence is continuous everywhere.

Comment: I added the solution-verification tag, in the future that is a helpful tag to use if applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposition 5.2 doesn't apply to the scalar multiplication $K \times X \to X$ since this is not a linear map: given $(a_1,x_1)$ and $(a_2,x_2)$ in $K \times X$, $(a_1+a_2)(x_1+x_2)$ and $a_1x_1+a_2x_2$ are not necessarily equal.

Thus, you need to show that the scalar multiplication is continuous *at every* $(a_0,x_0) \in K \times X$, not only at $(0,0)$.

To do this, consider $\varepsilon>0$, and set $$\delta := \min \bigg\{ \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|a_0|+1)}, \frac{\varepsilon}{2(\|x_0\|+1)},1 \bigg\}.$$
Then, for any $(a,x) \in K \times X$ with $(\max\{|a-a_0|,\|x-x_0\|\}=)\|(a,x)-(a_0,x_0)\|_{K\times X}<\delta$ we have
$$
\begin{align*} \|ax - a_0x_0\| 
    &= \|(a-a_0)x + a_0(x-x_0)\| \\
    &\leq |a-a_0| \|x\| + |a_0| \|x-x_0\| \\
    &\leq |a-a_0| (\|x_0\|+\|x-x_0\|) + |a_0| \|x-x_0\| \\
    &< \delta (\|x_0\|+\delta) + |a_0|\delta \\
    &\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2(\|x_0\|+1)}(\|x_0\|+1) + |a_0| \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|a_0|+1)} \\
    &< \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: You should just choose $\frac{\epsilon}{2|a_0|}$ instead of $\frac{\epsilon}{2|a_0| + 1} right?

Comment: @jsmith That works if $a_0 \neq 0$. Choosing $\frac{\varepsilon}{2|a_0|+1}$ saves us from working that case separately.